# Getting Cannot find 'linkBuilder' in scope Error when trying to shorten a url in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am using firebase dynamic urls to shorten my url. I read the whole documentation and i dont understand why the code is not working.

here is my code:

```
let link = "https://mywebsite.com/share/?shop="+concatenate(getKey!,"&title="+shopName.text!.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!,"&desc="+summary.text!.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!,"&img="+profileImgURL)

linkBuilder.shorten() { link, warnings, error in // i get an error here sayiny "cannot find linkBuilder in scope"
          guard let link = link, error != nil else { return }
          print("The short URL is: \(link)")
        }
```

what am i missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to define what `linkBuilder` is. Put this after `let link =`:

```
let dynamicLinksDomainURIPrefix = "https://example.com/link"
let linkBuilder = DynamicLinkComponents(link: link, domainURIPrefix: dynamicLinksDomainURIPRefix)
```

[*Documentation*](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/create)

Comment: what should i put in the dynamicLinksDomainURIPrefix?

Comment: @Derek I don't use Firebase so I'm not sure, but I think that's supposed to be the start of the website url for your dynamic links. https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/custom-domains